# Asp.net controller logic for opening views

Tags: c#, post, razor, view

im using mvc3 and code first scaffoling, this first snippet is from /post/index.cshtml

```
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id }) | 
        @Html.ActionLink("Comment", "Comment", new { id=item.Id })
    </td>
```

what do I add in the action to make the /Commment/Create.cshtml open with the id for the post popultated inn the Post field?

```
    public ActionResult Comment(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

this is the Post field

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostID, "Post")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("PostID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostID)
    </div>
```

Comment: Probably I do not understand your requirement well. But try to take a look at RedirectToAction method or at TempData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just do this?

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Comment", "Comment", new { id = Model.PostID })
</td>
```

Or do you want to get the current value from the DropDownMenu? In that case you need to use Javascrip/jQuery:

```
var currentPostId = $('#PostID').val();
```

And use it to update the ActionLink `href` property.